# Why can i not create a new object and set the properties?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm writing unit tests for a TypeScript app and i'm unable to define a new object and set the properties. All of my other tests that don't require an object class work properly and this only happens during the test, not when i use very similar code in a production method.

> Cannot set property 'eId' of undefined.

**Candidate.ts**

```
export class Candidate {
    public eId: string;
    public firstName: string;
    public lastName: string;
    public email: string;
    public address: string;
    public job: {
        title: string,
        eId: string,
    };
}
```

**test.ts**

```
import { Candidate } from '../../../src/api/models/JCandidate';

test('Parse API model to API V2', async (done) => {
    const cController = new CController(cService, log)
    const jCandidate = new Candidate();
    jCandidate.eId = '23423'; //Error here
    jCandidate.email = 'Rogers@test.com';
    jCandidate.address = '123 Test Ave';
    jCandidate.job.eId = '1235';
    jCandidate.job.title = 'Test Job Title';
    jCandidate.firstName = 'Test';
    jCandidate.lastName = 'Name';
    const kCandidate = await cController.parseJCandidateToK(jCandidate);
    expect(kCandidate.name).toBe(jCandidate.firstName + ' ' + jCandidate.lastName);
    expect(kCandidate.jobId).toBe(jCandidate.job.eId);
    done();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how an error can occur on the line you marked, but I would expect one on the `jCandidate.job.eId = '1235;'` line because you never created the `jCandidate.job` sub-object.  Try replacing:

```
jCandidate.job.eId = '1235';
jCandidate.job.title = 'Test Job Title';
```

with:

```
jCandidate.job = {eId: '1235', title: 'Test Job Title'};
```